# On the central extension of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-extensions

Let $G$ be a central extension of a group $K$ by the perfect group $H$ ($K$ is the normal subgroup).

The question is that  if $(|K|,|Mult(H)|)=1$ then can we say that $G=H \times K$?

I would be grateful if anyone could answer the question.

Comment: What does $Mult(H)$ mean in this context? If $(|K|,|H|)=1$ then this is an application of the [Schur–Zassenhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem)

Comment: @RobertChamberlain Yes, Derek is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess ${\rm Mult}(H)$ means the Schur Multiplier of $H$.

Assuming that all the groups are finite, the answer is yes, because $G' \cap K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Mult}(H)$ and hence $G ' \cap K = 1$.